# Align span text within li element

Tags: html, css

Using dataTables, I have a responsive table that produces the following HTML within the child row

```
<ul data-dtr-index="0" class="dtr-details">
   <li data-dtr-index="0" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="0">
      <span class="dtr-title">Pay No</span> 
      <span class="dtr-data">999</span>
   </li>
   <li data-dtr-index="3" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="3">
      <span class="dtr-title">DOB</span> 
      <span class="dtr-data">14 Sep 1951</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Using CSS, I would like the second span in each li (`dtr-data`) to have the text aligned to the right. Is this possible in CSS without having to amend the DOM to put the span in a div tag? Ideally I do not want to create my own custom rendere, so to be able to align the span text through CSS only would be ideal

Comment: Surely this is actually a `table` and not a list? Wouldn't a table be more semantic.

Answer (score 1):

You could use flexbox for this.

This would reset the `li` `display` property, which removes the bullet point, so you would need to reintroduce it.

Example:

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: -1em;
}

li:before {
  content: '•';
  padding-right: .5em;
}

.dtr-data {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul data-dtr-index="0" class="dtr-details">
  <li data-dtr-index="0" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="0">
    <span class="dtr-title">Pay No</span>
    <span class="dtr-data">999</span>
  </li>
  <li data-dtr-index="3" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="3">
    <span class="dtr-title">DOB</span>
    <span class="dtr-data">14 Sep 1951</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the li relative, and the span absolute right:0px. (or use float:right)

```
li {
    position: relative;
}

li span:nth-child(2){
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1

`float` the nested element in question (`.dtr-data`).

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.dtr-data {
    float: right;
}

li {
    max-width: 300px; /* for the sake of demonstration */ 
    clear: both; /* clear floats for good measure */
}
```

```html
<ul data-dtr-index="0" class="dtr-details">
   <li data-dtr-index="0" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="0">
      <span class="dtr-title">Pay No</span> 
      <span class="dtr-data">999</span>
   </li>
   <li data-dtr-index="3" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="3">
      <span class="dtr-title">DOB</span> 
      <span class="dtr-data">14 Sep 1951</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

#### Method 2

`float` the nested sibling element (`.dtr-title`) and declare `text-align` on containing parent.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.dtr-title {
    float: left;
}

li {
    max-width: 300px; /* for the sake of demonstration */ 
    clear: both; /* clear floats for good measure */
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul data-dtr-index="0" class="dtr-details">
   <li data-dtr-index="0" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="0">
      <span class="dtr-title">Pay No</span> 
      <span class="dtr-data">999</span>
   </li>
   <li data-dtr-index="3" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="3">
      <span class="dtr-title">DOB</span> 
      <span class="dtr-data">14 Sep 1951</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

#### Method 3

Declare `flex` on the containing parent element and align accordingly with `justify-content` property.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
li {
    max-width: 300px; /* for the sake of demonstration */ 
    display: flex; /* required for following property to apply */
    justify-content: space-between; /* to align end-to-end */
}
```

```html
<ul data-dtr-index="0" class="dtr-details">
   <li data-dtr-index="0" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="0">
      <span class="dtr-title">Pay No</span> 
      <span class="dtr-data">999</span>
   </li>
   <li data-dtr-index="3" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="3">
      <span class="dtr-title">DOB</span> 
      <span class="dtr-data">14 Sep 1951</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

*A note on `flex-box`:*
Since `flex-box` has limited to no support for legacy browsers (like I.E) for full browser support and compatibility refer to either one of the aforementioned alternatives.

**See browser compatibility:**

1. [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex)
2. [flex - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex#Browser_compatibility)

#### Method 4

`position` the nested element in question (`.dtr-data`) as `absolute` and offset alignment by declaring a `right` property value, declare `relative` positioning on the containing parent element so that the absolutely nested child element is positioned relative to its parent.
*note: this solution will most likely require responsive adjustments*

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
li {
    max-width: 300px; /* for the sake of demonstration */ 
    position: relative; /* required */
}

.dtr-data {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul data-dtr-index="0" class="dtr-details">
   <li data-dtr-index="0" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="0">
      <span class="dtr-title">Pay No</span> 
      <span class="dtr-data">999</span>
   </li>
   <li data-dtr-index="3" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="3">
      <span class="dtr-title">DOB</span> 
      <span class="dtr-data">14 Sep 1951</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```